# Use implicit differentiation to find tangent lines parallel to a given line

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

find the tangent lines of $9x^2 + 16y^2 = 52$ that are parallel to the line $9x-8y = 1$.

I have differentiated the first function to get $-\dfrac{9x}{16y}$ now I'm not sure how to relate this gradient to the second equation to get the tangent lines that are parallel.

Comment: What defines a line being parallel to another line?

Comment: What do you know about the slopes of parallel lines?

Comment: well if a line is parallel it has the same gradient, the differential is the gradient of the tangent. How do you relate that to the given straight line?

Answer (score 1):

Well you said two lines are parallel if they have the same slope...
So we know y' represents the slope of the tangent line...
So find y' and set equal to the slope of the line given to you.

Comment: I think I have it, The book answer is a little suspect which is not helping